# Wordpress Taxonomy if value=true then display div class

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to display a div class only when the taxonomy of a post is chosen. Is it faster to do this for 3,000-5,000 posts or is it better to create a custom post type?

The overall goal is to only show a customer based clickable object when a specific type of coupon is created. This will allow me to create two different pages. One page showing one type of post, and the other showing the different layout of another.

Am I thinking about this all wrong? Maybe there is a better way?

```
Layout 1 - Coupon Type 1
```

|----------------------------------------
|
|
|        Title_Title_Title_Title
|
|      Description~~~~~~~~~
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|
|
|----------------------------------------|

```
Layout 2 - Coupon type 2
```

|----------------------------------------
|
|
|        Title_Title_Title_Title
|
|      Description~~~~~~~~~    |----------------|
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      |-vote object--|
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      |---------------|
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|
|
|----------------------------------------|

Am I using the correct terminology here?

```
<?php
if (is_object_in_taxonomy( 'Coupon Types', 'Coupon Code – User Added' )) {
    echo '<?php clpr_vote_box_badge( $post->ID ); ?>
' ;
}
else if (is_object_in_taxonomy( 'Coupon Types', 'Printable Coupon – User Added' )) {
    echo '<?php clpr_vote_box_badge( $post->ID ); ?>
' ;
}
else {
    echo 'nothing' ;
}
?>
```

I found this post, but it doesn't match my scenario exactly:
[Wordpress conditional statements for taxonomy, term, inside a loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650485/wordpress-conditional-statements-for-taxonomy-term-inside-a-loop-not-working)

Thanks!

Comment: I want to note that this current code removes the voting box for all coupons. This also does not work:

    <?php
    if (get_the_terms( 'Coupon Types', 'Coupon Code – User Added'     )) {
    echo '<?php clpr_vote_box_badge( $post->ID ); ?>' ;
    }
    else if (get_the_terms( 'Coupon Types', 'Printable Coupon –     User Added' )) {
    echo '<?php clpr_vote_box_badge( $post->ID ); ?>' ;
    }
    else {
    echo '' ;
    }
    ?>

Comment: `is_object_in_taxonomy( 'Coupon Types', 'Coupon Code – User Added' `  are you sure you have a taxomony called "Coupon Code – User Added"?

Comment: There is a coupon type that I added called that. I'm pretty sure it's a taxonomy. It's like a custom category, post or something. It's a theme I purchased, so u am not entirely sure. How do I check? I clicked on posts and those are for the blog.

Comment: place this in a page template, you will the registered names   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies#Output_a_list_of_all_public_custom_taxonomies

Comment: ah, there we go. coupon_type is the taxonomy. Tested, and my code is not referencing the taxonomy correctly still. (get_term or is_object_in_taxonomy doesn't work)